# Are there downsides to `pip install -e .`?

Tags: python, pip

I am working on a project that has two repo's associated with it, and often do work on both simultaneously. This seems to be a classic case for pip's editable install, which is what I'm using. Moving forwards towards productionalization, I'm wondering if there are any downsides to installing in editable mode? Really a two part question:

- Are there downsides to editable installs in terms of performance?
- Are there downsides to editable installs in deployment, which would be worth having additional code to do a traditional install? Are there security/permissions/containerization/etc consequences I'm not realizing?

Answer (score -1):

There are no downsides in terms of performance.

Editable installs are for development. When deploying your code it is usually better to generate a release of your package, so you know exactly which version it is using. Create a tag in your version control system and reference it. It'll save you a lot of future troubles.

If you don't want to publish to a public repository or to setup a private one, you can [install directly from Git](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/). It is usually a nice trade off and you will have consistent releases.

Comment: > There are downsides in terms of performance.  -- no there aren't, editable installs are just fancy sys.path manipulation (same code just in a different place)

Comment: "Editable installs are for development.".  Can you explain why? What are the actual implications of it that make it inappropriate for deployment? I don't particularly care about versioning here, other parts of my setup have that handled.

Comment: @Sasha the problem is really versioning. You don't fix the release version of your library when you install in editable mode.

Comment: @AnthonySottile ops, I've forgot to put the "no" in my phrase and inverted the meaning. There a really _no_ downsides.

Comment: @neves Thanks. Your point about versioning might be relevant if I was installing directly from a repo, or another external source, but in this case, as I said, I have the versioning controlled by containerization and don't care. Seems like there's no other implications, then!